# Why is my .empty() not emptying the parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I cannot get the jQuery empty method to work on my appended HTML elements.
It's quite a simple problem seemingly, but it has me beat.

I've tried moving the empty method around in the code but I still cannot get it to empty.

Edit: It will not let me edit this unless there is more text so here is some more text.

My jQuery/JavaScript:

```
// Declares blank arrays
let monthHolidayName = [];
let monthHolidayDescription = [];
let monthHolidayDay = [];
let monthHolidayMonth = [];
let monthHolidayIsoDate = [];
              
// On change pushes the arrays with the current months data
$('#monthSelect').change(function(){
          
  var selectedMonth = $('#monthSelect').val();
  var numSelectedMonth = parseInt(selectedMonth) + 1;

  for(i = 0; i < result['data']['holidays'].length; i++){
    var holidayMonth = result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['datetime']['month'];
    if(holidayMonth === numSelectedMonth){
      // console.log((result['data']['holidays'][i]));
      monthHolidayName.push(result['data']['holidays'][i]['name']);
      monthHolidayDescription.push(result['data']['holidays'][i]['description']);
      monthHolidayDay.push(result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['datetime']['day']);
      monthHolidayMonth.push(result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['datetime']['month']);
      monthHolidayIsoDate.push(result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['iso']);
    }
  }

  // Empties the #holidays element <--------------------
  $("#holidays").empty();
  
  // Appends the data to the modal
  for(i = 0; i < monthHolidayName.length; i++){
    var holidayName = monthHolidayName[i];
    var holidayDescription = monthHolidayDescription[i];
    var holidayDay = monthHolidayDay[i];
    var holidayDayMonth = monthHolidayMonth[i];
    var holidayIsoDate = monthHolidayIsoDate[i];

    var dateParsed = Date.parse(`${holidayDay} ${holidayDayMonth}`).toString("MMMM dS");
    // Appends elements to #holidays with the data         
    $("#holidays").append(`<div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><div style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: center;">${holidayName}</div><div style="text-align: center">${holidayDescription}</div><small class="text-muted">${holidayIsoDate}</small></div>`);
  }          
});
```

My HTML code:

```html
 <!-- Calendar Modal -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="modal fade " id="calendar-modal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               
              <div class="modal-header"> 
                  <h1 id="modalTitle">Holidays</h1>
                  <button type="button" class="close btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
              </div>
              <!-- This is the body section of our modal overlay --> 
               <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
                <div class="btn-group dropright">
                  <select class="form-select form-select-sm mb-3" id="monthSelect"> 

                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group">
                  <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="holidayTitle">
                    Holidays in <span id="currentMonth"></span>
                  </button>
                  <span id="holidays">
                  </span>
                  
                </div>               
              </div>
               <!-- This is the footer section of our modal overlay  -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use so many different arrays? Things are much easier if you use a single array of objects.

Comment: Put your HTML code please.

Comment: you're never emptying the arrays. So every time you change the select, you add all of the new month's holidays to the arrays. Then you put all of them into `#holidays`.

Comment: `.empty()` works as it should. You'd see that if you commented out the loop that appends to it.

Comment: My HTML code is added.

Comment: I didn't know that was best practice, I'm learning at the moment so much appriceated

Comment: as I can check $("#holidays").empty(); working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to both `append` new data to your existing data while also deleting the old data. Your code is constantly referencing `append`, which implies that you want to keep the previous data, but your question asks about how to clear the `holidays` div, and then add the new holiday.

Answering your question, we don't need an array if we're always deleting the previous holiday information, instead we can use a [JavaScript Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) to hold the information. The other portion that you'll notice I changed is I took out the `for loop` you had. Since we have a *single* holiday, we don't need to iterate through an array. The following code should show how to work with a single holiday in an Object. Note that I did not change the HTML

```
// Declare an object with our empty parameters:
let holiday = {
  name: "",
  description: "",
  day: "",
  month: "",
  isoDate: ""
};
          
// On change pushes the arrays with the current months data
$('#monthSelect').change(function(){
      
  var selectedMonth = $('#monthSelect').val();
  var numSelectedMonth = parseInt(selectedMonth) + 1;

  for(i = 0; i < result['data']['holidays'].length; i++){
    var holidayMonth = result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['datetime']['month'];
    if(holidayMonth === numSelectedMonth){
      // console.log((result['data']['holidays'][i]));

      // Using object setter notation to change each key:
      holiday.name = result['data']['holidays'][i]['name'];
      holiday.description = result['data']['holidays'][i]['description'];
      holiday.day = result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['datetime']['day'];
      holiday.month = result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['datetime']['month'];
      holiday.isoDate = result['data']['holidays'][i]['date']['iso'];
    }
  }

  // Empties the #holidays element <--------------------
  $("#holidays").empty();

  var dateParsed = Date.parse(`${holiday.day} ${holiday.month}`).toString("MMMM dS");
  // Appends elements to #holidays with the data         
  $("#holidays").append(`<div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><div style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: center;">${holiday.name}</div><div style="text-align: center">${holiday.description}</div><small class="text-muted">${holiday.isoDate}</small></div>`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can manage this

```
   $("#yourDiv").html(""); // jQuery
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that this likely wouldn't work in this scenario since @HJP immediately re-appends the elements into the div